# AngularJS: Initial checkbox value not in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, coffeescript

I have got a form with a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="publish" id="publish" ng-model="data.publish" ng-true-value="Yes" ng-false-value="No"/>
```

Now I would like to have its initial value `'No'` (becuase it is unchecked) bound to the model without having to click on the checkbox. Is there a way besides setting the model value manually in the controller or using `ngInit`?

My script should work with different forms so manually setting model variables is no option. And the `ngInit` method seems rather inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a directive that works like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." init-cb ... />
```

The following code should do it:

```
m.directive("initCb", function() {
    return {
        require: ["ngModel"],
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            var ngModel = controllers[0],
            if( element[0].checked ) {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(attrs.ngTrueValue || true);
            }
            else {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(attrs.ngFalseValue || false);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hm, that would be a possibility but similar to `ng-init="data.publish=..."`.

Comment: Agreed, this is a more compact form of `ng-init=...`. However, since at initialization the *model* controls the form, I cannot think of another kind of solution.